# Why do I get an error when I try to run donkeycar server using the docker image?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've followed the instructions to build a [Donkey Car 2](http://donkeycar.com) and I'm trying to start the web server using docker.

When I try to run `bash start-server.sh` I get the following error:

```
start-server: Running Donkey server container...
Using TensorFlow backend.
Loading modules for server.
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/donkey/scripts/serve.py", line 12, in <module>
    w = dk.remotes.DonkeyPilotApplication()
  File "/donkey/donkey/remotes.py", line 175, in __init__
    self.pilots = ph.default_pilots()
  File "/donkey/donkey/pilots.py", line 84, in default_pilots
    pilot_list = self.pilots_from_models()
  File "/donkey/donkey/pilots.py", line 71, in pilots_from_models
    models_list = [f for f in os.scandir(self.models_path)]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/mydonkey/models'
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: My guess is that the app is not located in /root/....Have you accessed your docker container to see where the app is deployed? I think this should be defined in your Dockerfile as well? Did you set your APP_ROOT in the Dockerfile?

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with this, too, using docker on Windows 7. The script seems to claim to create files at /root but there is no such directory that I can find. Creating the files in ~ doesn't really help. At least in Windows, it really difficult for me to figure out where docker thinks the root of the filesystem is. It seems to think that my home directory is /c/emacs and puts everything preceded with "~" there, including ~/donkey and ~/mydonkey, but if I do an "ls /" it doesn't even show /c, but looks more like unix. I can't successfully run "docker run python ./setup.py" either.

Answer (score 2):

A [simple change](https://github.com/binary-bard/donkey/blob/master/start-server.sh) to the start-server.sh script fixed the issue for me.
Change line 4:

> mkdir -p ~/mydonkey

to this:

> mkdir -p ~/mydonkey/models

Comment: It might be helpful if detailed what the simple change was?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

1. Run `bash start-server -d` (with the -d flag) to open the docker with a terminal prompt.
2. Inside the docker terminal, run `python scripts/setup.py` to create the necessary folders in the `~/mydonkey` folder.
3. Now you can start the server by running `python scripts/serve.py` inside the docker terminal.

After you've collected some images you'll see them inside and outside docker in the `~/mydonkey` folder.

Comment: You should probably write up a dockerfile to do all this for you instead. With the dockerfile, you simply build your image with your latest code changes, then `docker run` that image and you will have deployed a container with your latest code. You really should never have to go in to your docker container to bring your app up.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) is the reference for dockerfiles

Comment: "docker run python ./setup.py" doesn't work for me and results in a "file not found" error, even using variations such as /donkey/scripts/setup.py, ~/donkey/scripts/setup.py, etc., etc., etc.  This is on Windows 7 in the "Docker Quickstart Terminal".  Help?